# VS Code project builder \ template starting point plugin? He

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

A few years ago there was a project by Microsoft to help projects 'start' in VS Code. It'd ask you what you were looking to do and it'd just template out the basic starting point and associated config files.

I cannot for the life of me remember what it was called and it was on my old companies slack, so I can't even go searching.

My issue is I always struggle to get that initial bit started when I start a new project.

I'm also open to suggestions on alternatives.

P.S. Sorry if this is the wrong part of StackOverflow, I'll post to the correct area if pointed at it.

Comment: do you mean the welcome page? See the `Help: Welcome` and `Developer: Reset Welcome Page Walkthrough Progress` commands.

Comment: Were you looking for [vsc scaffolding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfnielsen.vsc-scaffolding), or perhaps [Custom templates for dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates)?